# Given a Youtube video id, what's the quickest way to check if it's a valid video or not?

Tags: api, http, rest, youtube

When a user submits a video id, I need to know whether that id is actually a video on youtube.

Is there a simple REST api endpoint I can hit?

Answer (score 6):

The YouTube API has a [method](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries.html) to get the details of a video. It will return an error if the video does not exist.